# Incorrect overriding of "equals"?

Tags: java, equals

got stuck on the test tusk:

```
 class MyKeys {
 Integer key;
 MyKeys(Integer k) {
 key = k;
 }
 public boolean equals(Object o) {
 return ((MyKeys) o).key == this.key;
 }
}
```

And this code snippet:

```
Map m = new HashMap();
MyKeys m1 = new MyKeys(1);
MyKeys m2 = new MyKeys(2);
MyKeys m3 = new MyKeys(1);
MyKeys m4 = new MyKeys(new Integer(2));
m.put(m1, "car");
m.put(m2, "boat");
m.put(m3, "plane");
m.put(m4, "bus");
System.out.print(m.size());
```

So, my expected output would be "2", while it's actually 4. I guess there is some problem with correctness of overriding equals method. Any help is useful.

Comment: What confuses me more, is that SOUT m1.equals(m3) shows "true".

Comment: 1. You didn't override `hashCode`. 2. You compared `Integer`s with == instead of equals.

Comment: Yes, I *think* what's going on is the hash code.  Each of those hashes to a different value, so they each get stored individually.  Hence, the size is 4, for 4 objects.

Comment: Also, if the OP didn't know about the the pitfalls in that suggested duplicate link, then get a copy of *Effective Java* by Joushua Bloch.  Lots of useful advice in that book.

Comment: Unrelated: in `equals` check if `o` is null and if it's an instance of  `MyKey`

Answer (score 1):

You have to compare the object's key by using ".equals()" instead of "==". You also need to implement the hashCode() as required.

Comment: That doesn't answer the question

Comment: what's the question? ;)

Comment: original answer: `You have to compare the object's key by using ".equals()" instead of "=="`

Comment: ok, sorry, I didn't mean to confuse anyone by editing the answer. I meant to complain about the unspecific question in general.